# Change the word “Table” in only one table caption

Tags: tables, grouping, xltabular, tabularray

I'm using the `xltabular` with the `group`, because of the table is large and it occupies more than one page.
My document which is a thesis, I have two types of tables, the `tables` and the `frames`.
By default the `xltabular` is showing frame as a table, but is a `frame`. There is a way to change just this table to frame?
I've  used `\captionsetup[table]{name=frame}`
but it changes all the other tables captions.
[image]
And this `new table name #` is showing for all tables, which are real tables and not frames.
the code is :

```
\begingroup
\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{| *{5}{L|}}
    \captionsetup[table]{name=frame}
     \caption{Long table caption.}
     \label{long}
    \Xhline{1pt}
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{begin frame}\\
    \hline
\textbf{Chave} & \textbf{a}   & \textbf{b} & \textbf{c} & \textbf{d}\\
    \Xhline{0.5pt}
\endfirsthead
    \caption[]{Continuation}    \\
    \Xhline{1pt}
\textbf{Chave} & \textbf{a}   & \textbf{b} & \textbf{c} & \textbf{d}\\
    \hline
\endhead
    \Xhline{1pt}
\endfoot
     \hline
     \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{end frame}\\
     \Xhline{1pt}
\endlastfoot
...
...
...
\end{xltabular}
\endgroup
```

Anyone can help-me ?
Thanks a lot guys

**Edited: runable code**
I´ve changed the code according to the suggestion bellow and its not splitting the table to different pages and furthermore it is letting a very big empty space before the table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage[paperwidth=8cm,paperheight=6cm,width=7cm,height=4.5cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\DefTblrTemplate{caption-tag}{myframe}{
  Frame\hspace{0.25em}\thetable
}
\DefTblrTemplate{firsthead}{myframe}{
  \UseTblrTemplate{caption}{default}
  \vspace{0.5em}
  \hrule height 1pt
  \vspace{0.5em}
  \centerline{begin frame}
}
\DefTblrTemplate{lastfoot}{myframe}{
  \centerline{end frame}
  \vspace{0.5em}
  \hrule height 1pt
}
\NewTblrTheme{myframe}{
 \SetTblrTemplate{caption-tag}{myframe} 
 \SetTblrTemplate{firsthead}{myframe}
 \SetTblrTemplate{lastfoot}{myframe}
}

\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {Long frame caption},
  label = {longframe},
  theme = myframe,
]{
  colspec={*{5}{X}}, colsep = 3pt, rowhead = 1,
  cells = {font=\footnotesize}, row{1} = {font=\footnotesize\bfseries},
}
\hline[1pt]
  Chave   & a     &  b     & c     & d     \\
\hline[0.7pt]
  \lipsum[2-4]   & \lipsum[2-4]  & \lipsum[2-4]  & \lipsum[2-4]  & \lipsum[2-4]  \\
\hline
  \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4]  & \lipsum[2-4]    & \lipsum[2-4]  & \lipsum[2-4]    \\
\hline
  \lipsum[2-4]    & \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] \\
\hline
  \lipsum[2-4]   & \lipsum[2-4]  & \lipsum[2-4]  & \lipsum[2-4]  & \lipsum[2-4]  \\
\hline
  \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4]  & \lipsum[2-4]    & \lipsum[2-4]  & \lipsum[2-4]    \\
\hline
  \lipsum[2-4]    & \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] \\
\hline[1pt]
\end{longtblr}

Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text

\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {Long table caption},
  label = {longtable},
]{
  colspec={*{5}{X}}, colsep = 3pt, rowhead = 1,
  cells = {font=\footnotesize}, row{1} = {font=\footnotesize\bfseries},
}
\hline[1pt]
  Chave   & a     &  b     & c     & d     \\
\hline[0.7pt]
  \lipsum[2-4]   & \lipsum[2-4]  & \lipsum[2-4]  & \lipsum[2-4]  & \lipsum[2-4]  \\
\hline
  \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4]  & \lipsum[2-4]    & \lipsum[2-4]  & \lipsum[2-4]    \\
\hline
  \lipsum[2-4]    & \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] \\
\hline
  \lipsum[2-4]   & \lipsum[2-4]  & \lipsum[2-4]  & \lipsum[2-4]  & \lipsum[2-4]  \\
\hline
  \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4]  & \lipsum[2-4]    & \lipsum[2-4]  & \lipsum[2-4]    \\
\hline
  \lipsum[2-4]    & \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] \\
\hline[1pt]
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

The output is the following:
too many blank pages before the table/frame, the table/frame are cut off , and too many blank pages after the table/frame that were cut.

Thank again you all guys
[image]

Comment: Like longtable, xltabular uses a custom \caption which probably ignores \captionsetup.  You probably have some code to overcome this problem, which is no doubt the source of the difficulty, as \captionsetup makes local changes only.

Comment: Please always provide a compilable example, not some code segment. Also it is impossible to break in the middle of some `\lipsum` in the cell for long tables.

Comment: I have edited my answer for `\lipsum`. But it is not a good way to write plenty of text inside a single cell.

Comment: It didn't worked :(

Comment: Very late, but: long table can break between pages only between rows. Contents of cells are to large that one row can be fit on text area, consequently it spill out of the bottom of page.  You have two options: **(i)** write shorter text or **(ii)** use much smaller (unreadable, about 2pt)  font size for tables content.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to give the new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) a try, then it is easy to customize table captions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\DefTblrTemplate{caption-tag}{myframe}{
  Frame\hspace{0.25em}\thetable
}
\DefTblrTemplate{firsthead}{myframe}{
  \UseTblrTemplate{caption}{default}
  \vspace{0.5em}
  \hrule height 1pt
  \vspace{0.5em}
  \centerline{begin frame}
}
\DefTblrTemplate{lastfoot}{myframe}{
  \centerline{end frame}
  \vspace{0.5em}
  \hrule height 1pt
}
\NewTblrTheme{myframe}{
 \SetTblrTemplate{caption-tag}{myframe} 
 \SetTblrTemplate{firsthead}{myframe}
 \SetTblrTemplate{lastfoot}{myframe}
}

\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {Long frame caption},
  label = {longframe},
  theme = myframe,
]{
  colspec={|*{5}{X|}}, colsep = 3pt, rowhead = 1,
  cells = {font=\footnotesize}, row{1} = {font=\footnotesize\bfseries},
}
\hline[1pt]
  Chave   & a     &  b     & c     & d     \\
\hline[0.7pt]
  \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] \\
\hline
  \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] \\
\hline
  \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] \\
\hline
  \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] \\
\hline
  \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] \\
\hline
  \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] \\
\hline[1pt]
\end{longtblr}

\lipsum[1-10]

\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {Long table caption},
  label = {longtable},
]{
  colspec={*{5}{X}}, colsep = 3pt, rowhead = 1,
  cells = {font=\footnotesize}, row{1} = {font=\footnotesize\bfseries},
}
\hline[1pt]
  Chave   & a     &  b     & c     & d     \\
\hline[0.7pt]
  \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] \\
\hline
  \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] \\
\hline
  \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] \\
\hline
  \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] \\
\hline
  \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] \\
\hline
  \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] & \lipsum[2-4] \\
\hline[1pt]
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, because the content are some text for each cell. And I added some `ipsum`  the tables broke, and the vertical lines that is the difference between a table and the frame, The tables are without the vertical lines and the frames have vertical line.

Comment: @user2535338 Pease edit your question and provide a MWE (minimal working example).  Then I will see if I can help you.